# Is there a way to close VBA processes left open after a file is closed (due Titus Classification Add-In)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

Our office uses Titus Classification to identify a users file security levels. It operates in the Office environment as an Add-In. The new version of Titus (2019.0 SP1 18.4.1843.123) is causing a problem with Excel 2013 (15.0.5215.1000). Starting with the installation of this version of Titus, when you close an Excel spreadsheet, The VBA processes for that spreadsheet remain open, even though the file is closed. With the file closed you can access run or edit the VBA processes even though the spreadsheet is closed.
Titus is aware of this issue and is working on a solution. Until that option is released, is there a way to force close the processes when the file is closed or while it is closing?
Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Do you mean you can see the code in the VBEditor, even though the file is closed?

Comment: Stop the processes through the Task Manager?

Comment: Ben, yes, the spreadsheet is closed but all the VBA processes are still available to view and edit. If you exit and restart Excel, you can start fresh. But my VBA processes often opens and closes many files when processing. Sometimes the panes in the developer project windows become very full and I get an out-of-memory error. I was hoping that there was a way to dismiss the projects without having to restart Excel.